# Высота блоков. Что оптимально: % или px?

Tags: html, оптимизация, css

Как вы сами создаюте блоки для своего сайта? Процентами или пикселями? Хочу создать "длинный" сайт, т.е сайт состоящий из 8 подряд идущих блоков-страниц. Как бы вы сделали на моем месте, сделали бы с процентами или пикселями?

А позиции страниц как?

```
position: absolute;
top: 100%; (или пиксели тут)
top: 200%; и т.д?
```

так? Или? Хочу просто создавать с умом. А не как попало, не криво, а красиво. Спасибо заранее за советы

Answer (score 1):

У меня обычно так

HTML

```
<selector id="wrap">
   <div>Content random size</div>
</selector>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
   width:100%;
   haight: auto;
   float: right/left;
}
```

И дочерние элементы любых размеров родительский растянется сам.
Ну а дочерние элементы либо по аналогии, либо уже фиксировано.

Comment: а что с background-image? Ведь если ему не задать высоты, он не отобразится